# access files by folder in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to create an image picker that shows the list of all the device folders [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2ldZ.jpg) and their files on selecting a folder. I found a plugin storage_path but it is deprecated is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you will need to use the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) plugin in pub.dev